# How to make LibreOffice Calc look like Google Sheets?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to transition from Google Docs to LibreOffice for privacy concerns. Does anyone have any advice of how I could make it more minimalistic and clean like Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Well... It's a different program, with a bigger feature set and a user interface designed by different developers than Google Sheets, and with a different design philosophy and goal.

If you go to the "View" menu you can hide/show the various toolbars, formula bar, and status bar. That could help move it into more familiar territory, although you may lose some buttons you use a lot. You could also hide all the default toolbars then create a new toolbar (or edit an existing one) with only the buttons for the features you use frequently (View -> Toolbars -> Customize). That's probably where I'd start.

If you go to Tools -> Options, then open "Appearance" under "OpenOffice.org", you can set color palettes and such (you can even save your favorites as a preset). There may also be a few things in "View" under the Calc settings.

You won't be able to change the overall layout but by trimming excess fat off the toolbars and picking colors that you like you could certainly clean it up a little bit.

Libreoffice also supports Firefox personas. I think you will find [this article](http://andybrandt531.com/2013/02/customize-new-libreoffice-4point0/) very interesting, it goes over all the ways you have to customize it, including toolbars, personas, colors, etc. It will be a good place for you to start.

You might also want to consider leaving it unmodified for a bit while you learn it, before customizing. You may discover a few features that Sheets didn't have that you find you really like, and then you can include those in your customized toolbars as well.